# Hook up a light designed for car into a wall socket or battery source

Tags: electrical, transformer

I'm attempting to hook up the [Infrared LED LED Light Bar - 54W](https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/specialty-high-power-led-spot-lights/11-ir-high-powered-led-spot-light-18w/1607/) to either a wall socket or a battery source. I'd like to know what hardware and what wiring I need to accomplish this. Any embelishment on the parameters that are important would be appreciated so I can solve this type of problem in the future. Thanks. -Rik

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really isn't a home improvement question. It's pretty simple for an electronics question, but I'd still suggest the Electronics SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need a plug-in AC/DC converter (transformer) of 12-28 volts that provides enough current for the 54 watt consumption.

Divide 54 watts by the voltage of your selected transformer to calculate the amperage draw, and allow a 30% buffer or so. For example, 54 watts / 12 volts = 4.5 amps, so you'd want a transformer that provides at least 6 amps or so. The higher the transformer's voltage, the lower the current draw.

The power bar has a simple wire pigtail for connection, so you'll need to use appropriate crimp connectors or some other safe, insulated method.